How is it possible that polynomial $x^2 +x +2$ can't be written as binomial square but can give number that is square of some number?
$$
P(x) = x^2 + x + 2 = \bigl(x + \tfrac{1}{2}\bigr)^2 + \tfrac{7}{4}
$$
This function/polynomial doesn't have real roots or $4$ as constant but for $n = 1$, $P(x) = 4$.
I got confused when I was solving the problem where I needed to prove that this polynomial is not divisible by $49$.
I thought since $49$ is the square of $7$, if I prove that polynomials can't be written as a square of real numbers or don't have a factor that is a factor of $49$ would be the correct answer.
The reason I am asking this is because there is something in my knowledge about polynomials and natural numbers that I misunderstood.

If $p(x)$ could be expressed as the square of a polynomial with integer coefficients, then all its values at integers would be squares. But polynomials can take square values without being squares themselves! I mean, $f(x) = x$ takes square values infinitely many times but is not a square.

It does make sense.Thank you.I got confused because I know that for example if P(x)=1,the polynomial with integer coefficients can be the at most second degree or has two real roots,for prime number it would be degree of 3.

What is $n?{}{}{}$ What does "or $4$ as constant" mean?

This actually ends up being a quadratic diophantine problem (if you restrict to integers).
Diophantine problems are notoriously difficult, though some can be easy.

We distinguish between the factorization of a polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ in the polynomial ring, i.e. expressing it as a product of polynomials, vs. the integer factorization of $P(x_0) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for a particular integer $x_0$. In fact, if $P(x) = Q(x)^2$ for some $Q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then it would always be the case that $P(x)$ equals a perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}$. As an exercise you could try to show the converse of this statement. The polynomial $P(x)$ you defined in your question can equal a perfect integer square, but this is only true for a handful of integers $x$. Indeed, as another exercise you can show that $P(x) = x^2+x+2$ is not a perfect square for $|x|>2$.
